# Block traffic based on x-forwarded-for with Checkpoint IPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, firewall, checkpoint, x-forwarded-for

Say http/https requests are coming from a client behind an AWS elastic load balancer, and so Checkpoint sees the IP address of the load balancer as the source of the request. Is it possible to use the x-forwarded-for header in a request to configure an access policy rule in Checkpoint?

I see there are a few other posts which discuss how to deal with this with IIS, but I haven't been able to find a solution for Checkpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I have since confirmed that currently Checkpoint does not have any functionality for blocking based of x-forwarded-for header content except for in their geo-blocking policies. This of course does not allow for any user-defined sets of IPs/CIDR ranges. The functionality for configuring firewall rules based off the x-forwarded-for is supposed to be on the roadmap for Checkpoint, but they haven't put out a timeline for its implementation at this point.

One way to get around this is to use AWS Network Load Balancers, which unlike Classic Load Balancers or Application Load Balancers, do not change the original source IP of the request. This eliminates the need for header scanning.